# Recreated LZMA differs from the original after 332 bytes - possible?

Tags: compression, 7zip, lzma

Today I came across an LZMA-compressed file which was recognized and decompressed by the [LZMA SDK](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). My decompression parameters were `lc = lp = 0, pb = 2` with an 8MB dictionary size.

When I re-compressed it (without modification, using the same aforementioned parameters):

- The first 332 bytes I got were identical to that of the original compressed data
- Starting from the 333rd I didn't find any nontrivial sequence of bytes in common
- The recreated LZMA was 1 byte smaller than the original
- I was able to decompress it again to get the same file decompressed from the original

What I want is to recreate the original LZMA exactly as it is, because I'm concerned that the firmware I got the original LZMA from might not recognize the recreated LZMA in place of it.

I could use any information or hints regarding why the first 332 bytes are identical in both LZMA files while the rest are not. I've tried to find some compression parameter(s), other than the 4 I mentioned, that only the output *after* a specific offset may be subject to (I'm assuming LZMA decompression with the same parameters is injective, correct me if I'm wrong here). Haven't found any and there are too many combinations to try.

I thought referencing the original file is only necessary if my scenario is uncommon. In that case let me know and I'll create a link.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters lc, lp, pb, and dictionary size determine a distinct subformat of LZMA.
A compressed file can be decompressed correctly only with the correct values of those 4 parameters.
However, given those parameters, there is a huge number of ways of **compressing** data with LZMA.

- There are various LZ77 string matcher algorithms, and each one has many variants and parameters.
- Even with a given output of the LZ77 phase, there are various alternative ways to encode it in the LZMA format.

So the compressed file can be different, even with the same parameters, depending on the algorithms that were used for compression: different versions of LZMA SDK, or a different LZMA encoder.

Comment: Would you happen to know which of these compression factors (string matcher, version e.t.c.) is likely to change most of the output but not a 332-byte prefix of it?

Comment: The 332 bytes are certainly specific to your data. Don't you have other such files? Now, it is easy to see whether the LZ77 stream is the same, or not, in your two compressed data: you can customize a decoder and add a console or text file output to show what the LZ77 codes are.